# JOptionPane.showInputDialog() questions

Tags: java, swing

I am just beginning Java programming tonight (although I am a long time C++ coder).

I am experimenting with the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` function to gather user input.

However, it keeps setting the z-order of the input dialog underneath my IDE, with no notification on the start menu that a dialog is even there.

Is there any way to set options for it to appear at the top of the z-order, or perhaps even system modally?

Also, is there any way to limit the types of characters that can be entered into the text box of the input dialog, such as numeric types only?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JOptionPane** dialogs are always modal. There is no issue here. You will find your input dialog positioned in the center of the underlying JFrame (this), if you use it like this:

```
String myInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "myPrompt");
```

You will find it positioned in the center of your screen if you call it this way:

```
String myInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("myPrompt");
```

In both cases the dialog is modal by default.

In order to format and control the JTextField for your input, you should create your own JDialog, which is fairly easy and use JFormattedTextField inside with whatever restrictions you need.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options when it comes to limiting the input to certain types of chars etc. Either roll your own JDialog as mentioned, or validate the input once it's sent from the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` and re-pop the dialog if the input is invalid, preferably with a (new/added) message telling the user why :)

[How to Make Dialogs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `JOptionPane` dialog will be modal with respect to your Java application or Applet. It will **not** be modal with respect to your IDE.

Look at the arguments to [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#JOptionPane%28java.lang.Object%29). Notice that the `message` argument is an `Object` not a `String`.

When you pass a `String`, `JOptionPane` will display it as a prompt (a `JLabel`) followed by a `JTextField`.

However, you can also pass a `JComponent` or an array of `JComponent`. When you do this, the `JOptionPane` will display your components instead of the default `JLabel` and `JTextField`.

To limit the inputs to just digits you would supply a `JLabel` (for the prompt) and a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) with an [`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html). JavaLoby has a decent, quick overview of [JFormattedTextField with MaskFormatter](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48584.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **.matches** method with a **pattern** you define, it returns a **boolean** value so if it's true it'll go into your **if** statement the [] define the data you want the user to input the {} define how many characters, where the first number is a minimum and the second number is a maximium.
Letters work like this [A-Za-z]

The following is an example that would work for an Irish car license plate
[0-9]{2}\s-\s[A-Za-z]{1,2}\s-\s[0-9]{1,7}
"Two numbers from 0-9" " - " "one or two letters upper or lowercase" " - " "One to seven numbers from 0-9" 
e.g. "08 - Ky - 123"

```
String pattern= "[0-9]{1,8}";
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter data of numerical value")

if (userInput.matches(pattern))
```